# How to include revisioned files into .html after using gulp-rev?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gulp, gulp-rev

So I've created this task in gulp:

```
'use strict';
var gulp = require('gulp');
var gulpGlobals = require('./_gulp-globals.js');
var rev = require('gulp-rev');
var revReplace = require('gulp-rev-replace');


gulp.task('gulp-rev', function () {
    var sources = gulpGlobals.src + '/somefolder/**/*.js';
    var fileToInject = gulpGlobals.destination + '/somefolder/script.js';

    var outputFolderJs = 'webapp/dist/somefolder';

    return gulp.src(fileToInject)
        .pipe(rev())
        .pipe(revReplace())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(outputFolderJs));
});
```

And it creates additional file named like this for example:
`script-7c58e79612.js`

But how then do I include it in my html file instead of `script.js` ?
So fore example instead of this line in my `file.html`:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL}}/somefolder/script.js</script>
```

I could have this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL}}/somefolder/script-7c58e79612.js</script>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You would need `gulp-rev-replace` for this as you were trying, but you need to use it on your html file instead of your script file. For example, try modifying your tasks like this:

```
var manifestFolder = 'webapp/dist/manifest';

gulp.task("gulp-rev", function(){
    var sources = gulpGlobals.src + '/somefolder/**/*.js';
    var fileToInject = gulpGlobals.destination + '/somefolder/script.js';
    var outputFolderJs = 'webapp/dist/somefolder';

    return gulp.src(fileToInject)
        .pipe(rev())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(outputFolderJs))
        .pipe(rev.manifest()
        .pipe(gulp.dest(manifestFolder));
})

gulp.task("revreplace", ["gulp-rev"], function() {
    var manifest = gulp.src("./" + manifestFolder + "/rev-manifest.json");
    var source = gulpGlobals.src + '/somefolder/file.html';
    var outputFolderHtml = 'webapp/dist/somefolder';

    return gulp.src(source)
        .pipe(revReplace({manifest: manifest}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(outputFolderHtml));
});
```

This code is based on the second example of the [usage documentation](https://github.com/jamesknelson/gulp-rev-replace#usage) of `gulp-rev-replace`. More documentation and examples are also on that page.

Comment: thanks, I found gulp-inject as well, seems to do the job

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid the intermediate *manifest* step by swapping in the `gulp-rev-all` plugin.  It combines revisioning assets and rewriting references into one step.

```
// Imports
const gulp =   require('gulp');
const RevAll = require('gulp-rev-all');

// Tasks
const task = {
   resourcify() {
      const srcFiles =    'some/src/folder/**';
      const buildFolder = 'some/build/folder';
      return gulp.src(srcFiles)
         .pipe(RevAll.revision({ dontRenameFile: ['.html'] }))
         .pipe(gulp.dest(buildFolder));
      }
   };

// Gulp
gulp.task('resourcify', task.resourcify);
```

*Documentation:*
https://github.com/smysnk/gulp-rev-all

*Note:*
The project is controversial in that it combines two functions into one Gulp plugin.  However, combining the functions is warranted in this case because the combination solves a chicken and egg problem.

*Edited:*
Updated example code to support latest version of plugin.

Comment: I don't understand how will the index.html use the new js and css files?

Comment: @vini, It's the magic of the **gulp-rev-all** plugin... it knows the new revisioned file names, so it can also update the references inside **index.html**.  For example, `<script src=bundle.js></script>` becomes something like `<script src=bundle.7b7fd033.js></script>`.